# What can cause “multiply claimed blocks” on an ext4 drive?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, ext4, corruption, e2fsck

“Multiply claimed blocks” is an error reported by fsck when blocks appear to belong to more than one file. This causes data corruption since both files change when one of the files are written.

**But what can be the original causes of multiply claimed blocks? How are they created and how can I avoid them?**

Comment: They are not supposed to exist at all. Filesystem corruption can happen in any number of ways, including bad hardware… Which kernel are you running? [Sometimes there are bugs](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-ext4/20220110035141.1980-1-yinxin.x@bytedance.com/).

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks for writing! This question is not asked to solve a particular problem, but out of general curiosity for what possible reasons for this is, and you named one just there ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As stated](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14354#c109) very early by [Theodore Tso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Ts%27o) himself, there can be two **immediate** reasons for “*Multiply claimed blocks*” to be reported by fsck :

> One is that one or more blocks in the inode table get written to the
> wrong place, overwriting another block(s) in the inode table.

This is most often triggered by some kernel bug. (you can read T'Tso capable to describe some easily recognizable pattern => not at random as whatever spurious corruption caused by the outside would generate.).
This exceptionally occurs in the early times of new features for the EXT family of filesystems and mainly, because of rare race conditions :

- with [bigalloc](https://linux-ext4.vger.kernel.narkive.com/W3slUAni/patch-e2fsck-fix-can-t-find-dup-blk-error)
- [delayed allocation](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/linux-ext4/patch/4933BAC2.6080004@rs.jp.nec.com/),
- More, recently, as pointed out by *frostschutz* in OP's comments, [concerning the fast_commit feature.](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-ext4/20220110035141.1980-1-yinxin.x@bytedance.com/)

> The second case is one where the block allocation bitmap gets
> corrupted, such that some blocks which are in use are marked as free,
> and *then* the file system is remounted and files are written to the
> file system, such that the blocks are reallocated for new files.

These appear much more at random following some corruption which root cause is not likely to be a kernel bug.
This including unclean shutdowns, ill written applications, non-sensible mount options with regards to the hardware environment, misc. memory & other hardware faults.

Of course, one should not forget the possible responsibility of `fsck` itself producing erroneous reports or even at the root cause of the problem when badly trying to fix some other file system inconsistency, [there have actually been](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/e2fsprogs/+bug/1321418)

How can you avoid them, well, from what here-above told you can only expect to limit the probability of their occurrence :

- Stay low-tech ;-) Avoid setting all-brand-new features as soon as they become available,
- Use ECC memory and reliable storage devices,
- Fine-tune your filesystem options (offered at `mkfs` time) and select mount options wisely (in coherence with the environment),
- Run all untrusted softwares sandboxed.
- Ultimately [work as T'Tso](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14354#c43) in case of a crash, run [`e2croncheck`](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=23350) :

> What I'm actually doing right now is after every crash, I'm rebooting,
> logging in, and running e2croncheck right after I log in.   This
> allows me to notice any potential file system corruptions before it
> gets nasty … E2croncheck is much more convenient, since I can be doing
> other things while the e2fsck is running in one terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply claimed blocks can occur with Network/Shared Storage, eg Fibre Channel, iscsi, SAN, JBOD devices etc.  With these setups, if they are configured incorrectly, then two systems (Virtual or bare metal) can access the same blocks.  When incorrect setup, you can have blocks assigned to differnt block devices, and allocated to differnt devices.  As these systems are not aware of what the other system is doing with the blocks, they can cause these errors.

To avoid these errors, ensure you allocate block devices to only a single devices, restricting access to the block device to the one system.  Ensure where possible that "locks" are used.  Locks is when the blockdev is tagged as in use, and therefore can be used by another system (this is the simlified explanation).